# Cookie not set in request headers in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have created a cookie using the JS-Cookie package and it is saved in my browser, but the cookie is not set in my request header and is not sent to the server.

I use Axios.

My cookie example:

```
Cookies.set("myCookie", JSON.stringify(myData), {
      expires: 2,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
    });
```

Example of my Axios code:

```
axios.get("mayUrl", { withCredentials: true,});
```

I can send a cookie to React from the backend, but when I create a cookie in React, I can't send it to the backend. It seems that the browser ignores my cookie.

Thank you to those who help me

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers only have an effect when sent from the server, not the client

Comment: Without `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, the cookie  not sent. @mousetail

Comment: Those are response headers, not request headers. They need to be on the server side.

Comment: You seem to be making a same origin request anyways, so cross origin headers are not needed. Across origins it is impossible to send cookies.

Comment: @mousetail I am guessing front- and backend are probably using different ports here. That is irrelevant in terms of cookies, but for client-side requests it of course means that CORS restrictions apply now.

Comment: What is the actual value of `mayUrl`, and what URL are you on when you are setting the cookie?

Comment: If the front and backend are on a different url, it's **impossible** to send cookies. Use a different authentication method instead.

Comment: I am not asking for authentication, but for shopping cart. My cookie contains shopping cart information. I use React port ``localhost:3000'' and `IIS https` backend. When I send the request without the header, the cookie is still not sent. @ 
mousetail @CBroe

Comment: @mousetail _"If the front and backend are on a different url, it's impossible to send cookies."_ - that really depends on the "difference." Cookies are _only_ bound to the host name - not the port, not the protocol. So in a typical frontend on `https://hostname:80`, backend on `https://hostname:8080` setup, they could both share the cookies without problems. When it comes to making client-side requests though, CORS applies, because the different ports make them different origins.

Comment: @fqsof and what about the things I explicitly asked you about?

Comment: You asked  me what is my cookie information and in which url have I created a cookie? And I answered that the URL of the my React project is `localhost:3000` and my cookie contains the customer's shopping cart information. Did I understand correctly?@CBroe

Comment: It did not ask what the _base_ URL of your react app is, but what URL you are actually _on_ (what does the browser address bar show), when your code that sets the cookie executes. Is that _just_ `http(s)://localhost:3000/`, or is there a path? And what is the actual value of `mayUrl`?

Comment: My authentication was Cookie base, and because my server was in IIS, I had to set the cookie on the `Samesite=none secure`, and for this reason, I had to set my IIS to https, and when the authentication is done, there is no problem. When I create the cookie, my browser address bar is at `http://localhost:3000/item`. I don't understand what you mean by `the actual value of mayUrl`?@CBroe

Comment: @CBroe No, CORS requests will never send cookies. Even if the cookies are set for the correct domain

Comment: According to my codes, can you send me a code that work? both backend and frontend ? I will understand if your answer about conseptual backend.@CBroe @mousetail

Comment: @mousetail _"No, CORS requests will never send cookies."_ - yes they will, if instructed to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials